# Get Windows device handle from drive letter

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I am writing a file explorer tool for a filesystem I wrote for an OS I wrote. The explorer is in C# and I was wondering if it is possible to get a windows device handle from a driver letter (like C:) in .NET or using P/ Invokes

Comment: Wow! You've wrote an OS that runs .NET programs and supports Win32 API?!

Comment: Lol no I ment I was programming an OS in C but writing a utility on windows so I can exchange files between windows and my OS, lol

Comment: The OS that you wrote is irrelevant here. You just want to get a device handle from a drive letter right? Call `CreateFile` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To get a volume handle with P/Invoke you need a mounted volume.

To mount a volume with custom filesystem in Windows, you need a appropriate Windows driver for that filesystem. If you've written your custom OS and your custom filesystem, to write a Windows driver is a piece of cake for you, I'm sure.

But I have no idea, how your question is related to C# and even .NET. :)